# Remove Click Handler If Form Field Is Empty

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I somewhat have what I wish to do working but with one problem: it performs my btnSave function for each number of input elements that change. Here is my code:

```
$('#base-stats').on('change', 'input', function(){
    $('#btn-save').bind('click', btnSave);
});

function btnSave(){
    var valid = 1;
    character.currentChar.charName = $('#charName').val();
    character.currentChar.charLevel = $('#charLevel').val();
    character.currentChar.charLife = $('#charLife').val();
    character.currentChar.charES = $('#charES').val();
    character.currentChar.charInt = $('#charInt').val();
    character.currentChar.charStr = $('#charStr').val();
    character.currentChar.charDex = $('#charDex').val();

    $('#base-stats input').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
            console.log('Null field found at '+$(this).attr('id'));
            $('#btn-save').unbind('click', btnSave);
            valid = 0;
        }
    });

    if (valid) {
        $.post('checkchar.php',
            {c:character.currentChar.charName},
            function(data){
                if (data == 'null') {
                    $.post('savechar.php',
                        {c:character.currentChar},
                        function(data){
                            alert('Character successfully saved to the database.');
                        }
                    );
                }
                else {
                    if (confirm('Duplicate character name exists in the database! Overwrite current character?')) {
                        $.post('savechar.php',
                            {c:character.currentChar},
                            function(data){
                                alert('Character successfully updated in the database.');
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

So the way it currently works, my "save button" div begins without anything bound to it, then when a form input field changes it binds my btnSave handler function to the div when I click it. So to illustrate my issue, lets say I input two values into 2 of my 7 input fields. The console then logs the 5 empty fields twice over since two fields changed:

```
Null field found at charLife global.js:80
Null field found at charES global.js:80
Null field found at charInt global.js:80
Null field found at charStr global.js:80
Null field found at charDex global.js:80
Null field found at charLife global.js:80
Null field found at charES global.js:80
Null field found at charInt global.js:80
Null field found at charStr global.js:80
Null field found at charDex global.js:80
```

How can I prevent this from happening and still ensure no null fields are posted to my server? OR should I use a different method such as checking the null array values in my `savechar.php` file? I'd prefer to minimize interaction with the server though to save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your btnSave() method seems to be fine. Your problem is that you are binding that method to #btn-save's click event every time #base-stats is changed. Why are you doing that way? All you have to do is bind it once in the beginning, and then btnSave() will run whenever #btn-save is clicked, and your validation checks will kick in and do what you want. Just change the top of your script to this (I kept the unnecessary stuff in there and commented it out so you can see):

```
$('#btn-save').click(btnSave);
/**$('#base-stats').on('change', 'input', function(){
    $('#btn-save').bind('click', btnSave);
});*/
```